# Python is converting double quotes to single quotes in new variable

Tags: python

I'm trying to save a variable with double quotes in python, because I need to pass the double quoted JSON to a template and single quotes wont work with what I'm doing.  So I set the variable in python to:

```
json = {
  "auth": {
    "key": "auth-code-here"
  },
  "template_id": "id-here",
  "redirect_url": "url-here",
}
```

But immediate in python, it's saved as

```
{'redirect_url': 'url-here', 'template_id': 'id-here', 'auth': {'key': 'auth-code-here'}}
```

Is there a way I can save it as double quoted? Or will I need to process this in a django template to replace the single quotes for double quotes?

Thanks!

Comment: Show some code that you have made to achieve this.

Comment: Removed the apology, this is what this site is all about, programming questions.

Comment: The double quotes just tell python that it has a string.  Internally, those strings don't have any quotes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use a JSON module to do that. To Python, double- and single-quotes are interchangeable.

[Python has JSON abilities built in](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/json.html).